# Java two threads work with the same data (one get, one set)

Tags: java, sockets, java-threads

I'm taking my first steps with Java Sockets and Threads.

I want to try make synchonized connection with serwer where multiple threades adds their request to the queue and signle thread send all this request. In the meantime other threads wait for there resoults.

**How it's work:**

Client ask servert to log in by caling method

```
User user = logIn("sdasd");

public User logIn(String name){
        System.out.println("!Log in");
        //Function create request
        RequestHandler<User> request = new RequestHandler<>("logIn", name, out, results);
        //Request is added to queue
        requestQueue.addLast(request);
        RequestStatus status;
        //Thread who call this function wait for request to be handle (changed status)
        while (true){
            status = request.getStatus();
            System.out.println(status);
            if (status == RequestStatus.SUCCESSFUL) {
                System.out.println("Try to get result: ");
                User user = request.result();
                System.out.println(user.getName());
                return request.result();
            }
            if(status == RequestStatus.FAILED) {
                return null;
            }
        }
    }
```

In the meantime other thread send request to server:

```
new Thread(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        while(isConnected()){
            //is request to be handle?
            if(requestQueue.size() != 0){
                //remove request form queue
                RequestHandler request = (RequestHandler) requestQueue.removeFirst();
                //change request status
                request.setStatus(RequestStatus.IN_PROGRESS);
                System.out.println("!Request: ");
                System.out.println(request.getStatus());
                //process request
                request.request();
                //change request status to finished
                request.setStatus(RequestStatus.SUCCESSFUL);
                System.out.print("!Request end: ");
                System.out.println(request.getStatus());
            }
        }
        Iterator<Request> iterator = requestQueue.iterator();
        for (Iterator<Request> it = iterator; it.hasNext(); ) {
            Request request = it.next();

            request.setStatus(RequestStatus.FAILED);
        }

    }
}).start();
```

Inside class RequestHandler is process this code:

```
    @Override
    public void request() {
        try {
            //send commend
            out.writeObject(requestCommend);
            //wait for result (other thread handle this functionality)
            while(!results.containsKey(commend)){}
            //attach result
            result = (T) results.remove(commend);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

When the request is send to the server other thread wait for response for the server and add result to the HashMap:

```
            new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                while(isConnected()) {
                    try {
                        String commend = (String) in.readObject();
                        if(commend.charAt(0) == '@') { // @ mean its result of request
                            Object object = in.readObject();
                            //This is debug case to see everything work properly
                            if(object == null){
                                System.out.println("!I am null");
                            }else{
                                System.out.println("I am user: " +((User) object).getName());
                            }
                            System.out.println(commend);
                            results.put(commend, object);
                        }

                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }
        }).start();
```

This is it. Required code for this question:

```
public class ServerConnection extends Socket{
public static final int PORT = 8888;

private ObjectInputStream in;
private ObjectOutputStream out;

private LinkedList<Request> requestQueue;
private ConcurrentHashMap<String, Object> results;

public ServerConnection() throws IOException{
    super("localhost", PORT);
    System.out.println("Connected to the server.");
    in = new ObjectInputStream(getInputStream());
    out = new ObjectOutputStream(getOutputStream());

    requestQueue = new LinkedList<>();
    results = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();

    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            while(isConnected()){
                if(requestQueue.size() != 0){
                    RequestHandler request = (RequestHandler) requestQueue.removeFirst();
                    request.setStatus(RequestStatus.IN_PROGRESS);
                    System.out.println("!Request: ");
                    System.out.println(request.getStatus());
                    request.request();
                    request.setStatus(RequestStatus.SUCCESSFUL);
                    System.out.print("!Request end: ");
                    System.out.println(request.getStatus());
                }
            }
            Iterator<Request> iterator = requestQueue.iterator();
            for (Iterator<Request> it = iterator; it.hasNext(); ) {
                Request request = it.next();

                request.setStatus(RequestStatus.FAILED);
            }

        }
    }).start();

    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            while(isConnected()) {
                try {
                    String commend = (String) in.readObject();
                    if(commend.charAt(0) == '@') { // @ mean its result of request
                        Object object = in.readObject();
                        //This is debug case
                        if(object == null){
                            System.out.println("!I am null");
                        }else{
                            System.out.println("I am user: " +((User) object).getName());
                        }
                        System.out.println(commend);
                        results.put(commend, object);
                    }

                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }).start();
}

public User logIn(String name){
    System.out.println("!Log in");
    RequestHandler<User> request = new RequestHandler<>("logIn", name, out, results);
    requestQueue.addLast(request);
    RequestStatus status;
    while (true){
        status = request.getStatus();
        System.out.println(status);
        if (status == RequestStatus.SUCCESSFUL) {
            System.out.println("Try to get result: ");
            User user = request.result();
            System.out.println(user.getName());
            return request.result();
        }
        if(status == RequestStatus.FAILED) {
            return null;
        }
    }
}

public ArrayList<Room> getListOfRooms(){
    Request<ArrayList<Room>> request = new RequestHandler<>("listOfRooms", out, results);
    requestQueue.addLast(request);
    while (true){
        RequestStatus status = request.getStatus();
        if (status == RequestStatus.SUCCESSFUL)
            return request.result();
        if(status == RequestStatus.FAILED) {
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

}

RequestHandler looks like this:

```
public class RequestHandler<T> implements Request<T>{
private T result;
private RequestStatus status = RequestStatus.NEW;
private ObjectOutputStream out;
private String commend;
private String requestCommend;
private ConcurrentHashMap<String, Object> results;

public RequestHandler(String commend, String parameters, ObjectOutputStream out, ConcurrentHashMap<String, Object> results) {
    this.commend = "@" + commend;
    this.requestCommend = "?" + commend + ":" + parameters;
    this.out = out;
    this.results = results;
}
public RequestHandler(String commend, ObjectOutputStream out, ConcurrentHashMap<String, Object> results) {
    this.commend = "@" + commend;
    this.requestCommend = "?" + commend;
    this.out = out;
    this.results = results;
}
@Override
public void request() {
    try {
        out.writeObject(requestCommend);
        while(!results.containsKey(commend)){}
        result = (T) results.remove(commend);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

@Override
public T result() {
    return result;
}

@Override
public RequestStatus getStatus() {
    return status;
}

@Override
public void setStatus(RequestStatus status) {
    this.status = status;
}
```

}

The output looks like this **WHEN ITS WORK**:

```
Connected to the server.
!Log in
NEW
IN_PROGRESS
...
IN_PROGRESS
!Request: IN_PROGRESS
IN_PROGRESS
...
IN_PROGRESS
I am user: sdsad
@logIn
IN_PROGRESS
IN_PROGRESS
SUCCESSFUL
!Request end: SUCCESSFUL
Try to get result: 
sdsad
```

But when I **COMMENT** one debug msg I got this:

```
Connected to the server.
!Log in
!Request: IN_PROGRESS
I am user: dfdsfsdf4324
@logIn
!Request end: SUCCESSFUL
```

And the loop while(true) never end becouse I got always status IN_PROGRESS.

That's why I want to ask you why it's happen? Is Java have some weird way to optimalize output of functions to make is faster and is it thinking if it was reapet milion times so it has to be this state always?

Comment: It's not easy to follow your code but aside from `ConcurrentHashMap` I don't see any other attempt on synchronization, e.g. `RequestHandler`  and `requestQueue` are neither threadsafe nor is access to them synchronized. Thus you might run into race conditions and even broken data (e.g. changing a linked list concurrently might actually mess up the internal `next` and `prev` references and send your application into an endless loop).

Comment: I think you need to simplify your presentation code and explain why the output is wrong after you comment one debug msg.

Comment: I will try make it simpler

Comment: I updated my question to show you how it work. To be clear there are 3 threads one is for send data to server one to receive data from server and one to request some data from the server.

Comment: ```But when I COMMENT one debug msg I got this:```  Which line did you comment? Besides, you should set ```requestQueue``` to be thread safe, cause it's being reached by multiple threads.

Comment: In logIn function I commented `System.out.println(status);` and I change requestQueue to ConcurrentLinkedQueue. Problem is still the same.

Comment: Massive overkill here. You don't need any of this. Just have each thread do its own requesting and responding within a block that is `synchronized` on the socket. All those busy-wait loops are a particularly poor idea, and `while(isConnected())` is a misuse of the API. It doesn't do what you think.